# NTLM is automatically added instead of Bearer in AJAX Calls while calling API

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, authorization, ntlm, bearer-token

In my website, something weird is happening while running in Internet Explorer. My website and API are hosted separately. API is having anonymous authentication with token based authorization. MVC website is having windows authentication. Most of the times everything works as expected. But sometimes what happens is while calling the API from javascript my Authorization is headed changed to `NTLM` instead of `Bearer`. I am giving some screenshots of the same scenario.

Successful API Call:

[image]

401 Unauthorized Call:

[image]

My Ajax is as follows:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: src,
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    data: (parameters),
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token')
    },
      contentType: 'application/json'
    dataType: 'json',
    success: successCallback,
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        ErrorPopup("error occur");
    }
    ,
    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token')); }
});
```

I have debugged all API calls and always authorization header is set to `Bearer ...` still, somehow some way `NTLM` is taking control of it and making my API calls unauthorized. Please share some insights how could I solve this. I cannot change authentication in `IIS` as it's beyond my control. If you need any more inputs I can provide that too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a redundancy in your authorization headers (headers array + beforeSend). Remove one of them and test (reason : RFC 2616 says that several headers with the same name should be concatenated on the same line, and maybe the server is replying with an NTLM authorization request to such a request that it doesn't allow).

Comment: I did the changes and deployed. It worked for some time until I close the browser. It's like the if IE gets NTLM header from its previous request it just keeps on adding to all AJAX calls in the subsequent requests. And they all go 401 unauthorised. Please note : NTLM is added automatically by IE to authorise MVC web pages.

Comment: Do you mean that the changes improved the behavior ?

Comment: Maybe, look around cache problems ( cache: false )

Comment: another thing to be noted here. If I open IE in In-Private Mode. The website works fine. And again coming back on original version the website just behaves abnormally again. In chorme I don't face such issue either.

Comment: Private Mode disables caching. As I suggested, add cache : false to your AJAX calls.